I am not able to import the package when i hover the mouse on webdriver text after configuring selenium jar files to eclipse
I have configure the selenium jar files but after writing the simple program , on mouse hover import package option not showing . In attachement you can see configure jar files
Need show option for importing package when i hover the mouse on WebDriver text

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
